# Best way creating left/right border

Tags: css, html, css-float, border

I currently have the following layout for my webpage:

```
  <div class="content-body">
    <div class="left-content-bar siteborder"></div>
    <div class="inner-content">
    ... some content
    </div>
    <div class="right-content-bar siteborder"></div>
  </div>
```

I have made a repeating background-image for left and right content bar. I want the bar to always go from the top of the page to the end of the page. My current problem is, that the bars only take as much space as the inner-content (the bars end at the bottom end of the content)

I found a solution, so that the bars will always go to the bottom, but this includes a min-height which I don't like, because it will have a lot of whitespace with a small screen resolution.

See this css for my current solution (The height will always be minimum 1000px with this, and this shouldn't be):

```
.content-body{
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
min-height: 1000px;
height: auto !important;
height: 1000px;
}
.left-content-bar{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width: 10px;
    background-image: url(/default/images/content-left.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    padding-bottom: 32000px;
    margin-bottom: -32000px; 
}
.right-content-bar{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width: 14px;
    background-image: url(/default/images/content-right.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    padding-bottom: 32000px;
    margin-bottom: -32000px;    
}
.inner-content{
float:left;
width:956px;
position: relative;
height: auto;
min-height: 100% !important;
}
```

I hope that anyone can give me a better solution than my current

Comment: Including a jsfiddle link showing the current approach/problem is also useful.

Comment: What does the page HTML look like?  For this question, we almost need to see everything from `<body>` and all descendants.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NFcHJ/2/ here a jsfiddle... as you can see, the borders go down 1000px at the moment because of the min height, but if I remove them and the huge margin-padding, it looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NFcHJ/4/ (the borders are hidden because they have no actual height)

Comment: position absolutely the divs directly with height of 100% and left, top, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this a bit differently. With the same html as your sample, my css would look something like this:

```
.left-content-bar{
    position:fixed;
    width: 10px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background:url(/default/images/content-left.png) repeat-y;
}
.right-content-bar{
    position:fixed;
    width: 10px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background:url(/default/images/content-right.png) repeat-y;
}
.inner-content{
    padding: 0 10px; /* same padding left and right as the width of the sidebars */
}
```

I positioned the sidebars fixed. By setting both the bottom and the top property to 0 they stretch up to the height of the viewport. By then adding some padding to the actual content wrapper I make sure the sidebars and the content don't overlap.

I set up a small example to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/4Swvu/1/

Feel free to ask if you want some more explanation.

**Edit:**
If you want the sidebars on your content, rather then on you viewport, you could slightly adapt the code. The technique also works with position absolute so you could make your css look something like this:

```
.content-body {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;  
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.left-content-bar{
    position:absolute;
    width: 10px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background:#cff;
}
.right-content-bar{
    position:absolute;
    width: 10px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background:#cff; 
}
.inner-content{
padding: 0 10px; /* same padding left and right as the width of the sidebars */
}
```

and the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Swvu/5/

Comment: This doesn't look too bad, but the problem is that the positions are fixed, so the borders will be on each side, but the content should only be 1000px wide with the borders touching the content, not the whole screen

Comment: @Xavjer Not sure if I understand what you are after, but the same technique can be used with position absolute. Something like this perhaps? http://jsfiddle.net/4Swvu/2/

Comment: This is close to the desired result, but with this, if the content is smaller than the height of the page, the border stops, but I want the border to still reach the bottom (see http://jsfiddle.net/4Swvu/4/ )

Comment: add a height of 100% to your body and html, and set a min-height of 100% to the wrapper. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4Swvu/6/

Comment: This solution will work, but now I always have a scrollbar (it seems that the content exceeds the 100% ??), do you have any recommendations on how i could do this even better :)? I will mark you as solver tomorrow :)

Comment: you should reset the css. Use something like this http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ (best practice, I always use it!) or just set the margin end padding on your body and html to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use `inline-block` instead of `float` ?

Using float was originally made to display text around a picture, not to display divs the way you like (move away from floats if you can).

Anyway, using `display:inline-block;` you can put the 3 divs beside each other, and have the left and right column reach the bottom.

```
.content-body{
    height:1000px;
}
.siteborder{
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.inner-content{
    width:150px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Live example : http://jsfiddle.net/8vQrU/

Comment: Also with your solution, I don't want to set the height of the content-body, I want that if the content-body height is smaller than screen height, the borders should continue to the end of the page